# I want show different url and execute different url

Tags: .htaccess

I want show below url 
http://example.com/folder1

and execute url is

http://example.com/?test=folder1

Comment: in what technology are you programming. add those  details also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .htaccess file try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)$ index.php?test=$1 [L,NC]
```